# Protractor browser wait for boolean Condition

Tags: webdriver, protractor, wait

I'm trying to create a wait condition that will execute a script and based on the return value will will determined if it need to wait or not.
I'm using protractors executeScript functionality and browser wait:

```
this.activeConnections = function(jsl) {   
console.log("Inside Active Connections");
switch (jsl) {
case checkEnum.jQuery:
console.log("Jquery Enum");
return browser.executeScript("return jQuery.active;").then(function(count) {
console.log("The count is "+count);
return count == 0;
});
default:
browser.logger.info("No asynchronous check performed.");
break;
}   
};
```

I was expecting the wait condition to wait until the Executed script would evaluate to true but that is not working

```
this.waitForActiveConnections = function () {
console.log("Inside Wait for Active Connections");
var condition = until.and(this.activeConnections(checkEnum.jQuery),false);
console.log("Whats this condition "+ condition);
return browser.wait(condition,30000);
};
```

Comment: Got it working in simplified version: `this.waitForActiveConnections = function () {
        console.log("Inside Wait for Active Connections");
        return browser.wait(function(){
            // Wait until condition is true.
            return browser.executeScript("return jQuery.active;").then(function(count) {
                console.log("The count is "+count);
                    return count == 1;
            });
          },3000);
    };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that your custom Expected Condition *needs to return an executable - a function* that `browser.wait()` is going to execute continuously. Something like:

```
this.activeConnections = function(jsl) {   
    return function () {
        switch (jsl) {
            case checkEnum.jQuery:
                return browser.executeScript("return jQuery.active;").then(function(count) {
                    return count == 0;
             });
            default:
                browser.logger.info("No asynchronous check performed.");
                return true;
                break;
        }   
    }
}
```